# Units of the exponential function

Tags: exponential-function, physics, dimensional-analysis

What is the dimension of $e^x$ given the dimension of x is L?

My first thought was that it’s a completely different type of unit as $L^3$ is well-defined, but $3^L$ isn’t.

However, I realized that $e^x= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ has a power series, which would mean that it has all the units all at once.

But the problem is that this power series was formulated with no regard for dimensions, and the original would have been $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \frac{d^n f}{dx^n}$ where the units of $x^n$ in the numerator and $dx^n$ in the denominator cancel out and leave the units of $f$. Now we’re at square one.

There’s one important property of $e^x$ that could be leveraged: $e^a e^b = e^{a+b}$. This means that it has units of $L^0$, $L^\infty$, or $L^0+L^\infty$.

I don’t really know where to go from here.

Comment: It works if $x$ is dimensionless. Same for the trigonometric functions. Where are you seeing $e^x$ where $x$ is **not** dimensionless?

Comment: I know it works if $x$ is dimensionless, but I was thinking to myself a while back about this neat thought experiment.

Comment: I also just remembered seeing $e^{v\cdot \nabla} f(x)= f(x+v)$. It’s called the shift operator.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret $L^\infty$, so that leaves $L^0$ by your calculation on $e^a e^b.$ And $L^0$ is what we call "dimensionless".

Comment: @LaveCave $v$ has the same dimension as $x$, while $\nabla$ has dimensions as $1/x$, so $v\nabla$ is dimensionless